# $A^{\circ}$, $\overline{A}$, $\partial A$ of $A := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \in (0,3)$ and $y > x^2 \}$

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Let $A := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \in (0,3)$ and $y > x^2 \}$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I want to find the sets $A^{\circ}$, $\overline{A}$, $\partial A$.

I don't quite get what the set looks like because usually we have something like $a^2 + b^2 \leq 1$ which would represent a circle. How can I visualize the set above?

I would say

$A^{\circ}$ = $]0,3[ \text{ x }]0,3[$

$\partial A = (0,3) \cap \mathbb{R}^2$

$\overline{A} = (0,3) \cup \mathbb{R}^2$

Is that correct/wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For boundary, I think you are correct. However, notation can be cleaned as (0,3).
- For closure, if you can define a bijection from closure to $\mathbb{R}^2$ you are correct. Also, your notation can be cleaned as just writing $\mathbb{R}^2$
- For interior, you are correct.
- Thus, if you can show that your definiton of closure is valid (i.e. define a bijection from closure to $\mathbb{R}^2$) then you are correct.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me how I can define a bijection from closure to $\mathbb{R}^2$?